# Billion-dollar trick

Tags: phrases

What you would use better?

> a)    A billion-dollar trick

or

> b)    A billion dollars trick

or

> c) something different

---

The context is something like:

> He showed me {a|b|c}

Comment: Any question that h/b answered should be good for the upvote @Hellion. Can you explain what is wrong with this question? It would be good to know, not to make the mistakes again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "a trick that saves [or costs] a billion dollars", then the expression is "a billion-dollar trick".

The hyphen is necessary because *billion* modifies only *dollars* (not *dollar trick*); why the word *dollar* is not pluralized I don't know, but it isn't.